# code sequence in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am new to node.js and I thought I was beginning to understand asynchronous functions, but this code made me think that I did not understand it correctly anyway.

I am preparing for an insert to mongoDB with mongoose, and the object to insert is post. What made me wonder is that not always `post.kunde` or `post.leverandor` is set before the insert.

I thought that as long there is no asynchronous function, the code should execute line by line.

```
function create_post(account, dato, fakturanummer, bilag, bilagstype, supplier, customer, 
    descr, moms, amount, saldo, comId  ) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var post = new Posteringer;
        post.konto = account;
        post.dato = dato;
        post.fakturanummer = fakturanummer;
        post.bilag = bilag;
        post.bilagstype = bilagstype;
        if (Object.keys(supplier).length) {
            post.leverandor = supplier;
        }
        if (Object.keys(customer).length) {
            post.kunde = customer;
        }    
        post.tekst = descr;
        post.moms = moms;
        post.belob = amount;
        post.saldo = saldo;
        post.companyId = comId;    
        var promise = Accounts.findSingle(comId, account).exec(); 
        promise.then(function(acc) {
            post.navn = acc.Navn;
            console.log(post);
            post.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {console.log(err.message);}
                    resolve(true); 
            });               
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems to me that you're trying to find and edit. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few things wrong here.  A promise is basically saying "hey, I'm not done doing my stuff yet, but I'll promise to get this to you when I figure out all the things I need to do."

I am not entirely sure how you are calling this, but think of this like a big callback function.  So after this you'd have something like,

```
create_post(......).then(
                         function(post){ 
                              post.save(function(err){
                                    if (err) {console.log(err.message);}
                                 });
                         });
```

The real issue I see is  you are only resolving one promise.  I am not 100% sure if you have to resolve the Mongo promise, unless you are using bluebird promises with it.  Your first promise never gets returned though.

I will redo your code, I think this should work:

```
function create_post(account, dato, fakturanummer, bilag, bilagstype, supplier, customer, 
    descr, moms, amount, saldo, comId  ) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var post = new Posteringer;
        post.konto = account;
        post.dato = dato;
        post.fakturanummer = fakturanummer;
        post.bilag = bilag;
        post.bilagstype = bilagstype;
        if (Object.keys(supplier).length) {
            post.leverandor = supplier;
        }
        if (Object.keys(customer).length) {
            post.kunde = customer;
        }    
        post.tekst = descr;
        post.moms = moms;
        post.belob = amount;
        post.saldo = saldo;
        post.companyId = comId;    
        var promise = Accounts.findSingle(comId, account).exec(); 
        promise.then(function(acc) {
            post.navn = acc.Navn;
            console.log(post);              
        });
        return (err ? reject(err) : resolve(post));

    });
}
```

Then when you call this function call it like in my first example!

```
create_post(......).then(
                         function(post){ 
                              post.save(function(err){
                                    if (err) {console.log(err.message);}
                                 });
                         });
```

Literally what you are saying is if this resolves and I get my data without any errors, send back post.  Then pass post into my callback function and do whatever you want to do with it.

Edit:

Make sure you always return something from your promises, as far as I know the async call will never resolve as it never receives anything.  Although someone might have an example where this isn't true.

Comment: Thank you Morgan G. I followed your advise and it make sense, but the if statement has not set post.kunde before the promise return: resolve(post).

Comment: Are you passing in an object with keys, and not an array to customer?  I imagine you are but just making sure.

Comment: Yes - I am passing customer object with key.
Just for now I made it work putting the promise into a async.series where every if - statement is in its own function.
But my problem is that I still not understand. Are if-statements asynchronous?

Comment: Ah yes, so everything in node is non-blocking!  So that if statement was probably not processing fast enough.  One thing you could do to make it look a little bit nicer is chain promises together with promise.then().  Or you can have nested promises whichever you think is a cleaner solution.

Comment: I just found an code error in the code before the promise, that delayed the customer object. Now it is working and I could take the async.series away from the if statement again.
Anyway your answer made me organize my code in a better way. Thank you very much